# python datetime calculation not trimming to milliseconds

Tags: python, datetime

Doing the following calculation to take 30 days of the current date using the date-time module. The calculation is correct but it's not trimming milliseconds to 3 digits. any idea how I can implement it?

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
datetime_limit = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')[:-3]
datetime_limit = datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30)
```

Comment: even simpler: use `isoformat` with a `timespec`, e.g. `datetime.now().isoformat(timespec="milliseconds")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last digits are added when you do the calculation with timedelta.

```
from datetime import datetime,timedelta
datetime_limit = str(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=30))[:-3]
print(datetime_limit)
```